# Application running on android 4.2.2 but not running on 4.4 or higher

Tags: android

I am working on a project that will display pictures,play music and videos the app runs fine on 4.2.2 but not running properly on 4.4 or higher.
I used android studio 1.1 later i uninstalled it and installed 2.2 still faced same problem when i run on 5.1 the app crashed. please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No stack trace of error, no clue.

Comment: You have not provided enough information.

Comment: Share log error and manifest file

Comment: Application show no error in android studio the problem is after i install the apk on a real device

Comment: If i installed the apk on phone running on android 4.2.2  and tablet running on 4.4.2 it runs perfectly but picture will not fit the screen. if i do same on phone or tablet running on 4.4.4 or 5.0 higher the app crashed. I used AS 2.2, minimum sdk API 14 Android 4.0(IceCreamSandwich)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing KitKat and lollipop. I realised that they are not properly installed so I re installed and the problem is gone.